# Confusion about the definition of "degree" of continuous closed maps.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, definition

I'm reading Rotman's Algebraic Topology and the definition of degree is as given:

> If $f : (I, \{0,1\}) \rightarrow (S^1, 1)$ is continuous, define the **degree** of $f$ by: $$\deg f = f'(1)$$ where $f'$ is the unique lifting of $f$ with $f'(0) = 0.$

What I don't understand is why $f'(1) \neq f'(0)$.

If a lifting of $f$ is defined as: $f' : (I, \{0,1\}) \rightarrow (R,t_0)$ (where $t_0 \in \Bbb Z$) is a pointed map and $\exp : (\Bbb R, t_0) \rightarrow (S^1, 1)$ and pointed maps preserve base points $\Rightarrow$ $f'(0)$ should equal $f'(1)$?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Take $f'(t) = t$, so $f'(t)=1 \ne 0 = f'(0)$. And $f'$ is the unique lifting of $f(t) = (\cos(2 \pi t), \sin(2 \pi t))$ with $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: I think what you are missing is that the domain $I$ of the function $f$ and its liftings $f'$ should be regarded as a pointed space with just the single base point $0$. The other endpoint $1$ should not be regarded as a "base point" for this discussion, despite the requirement that $f(0)=f(1)=1$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm confused now after re-reading the definitions, how can $f$ even have a lift if it's a pointed set from $(I, \{0,1\}) \rightarrow (S^1, 1)$ when lifts are defined with single points?

Comment: The definition of a lift of $f$ as you give it in your question has some stuff that doesn't belong. A lift of $f : I \to S^1$ *should* be defined as any continuous function $f' : I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\text{exp} \circ f' = f$. With that definition of lift, the definition of the degree of $f$ works exactly as stated.

Comment: So the notation of a pointed map $f : (X, x_0) \rightarrow (Y, y_0)$ is the same as "$f : X \rightarrow Y$ with $f(x_0) = y$"?

Comment: Yes. I don't know Rotman's book, but that's exactly what it means in various other algebraic topology books I'm familiar with: Hatcher; Spanier; ...

Answer (score 0):

You should think about it as $(I,\{0,1\},0)$, $(S^1,\{1\},1)$ and $(\Bbb R,\Bbb Z,t_0)$.

The notation $(I,\{0,1\})$ probably just is used to suggest that $0$ and $1$ are mapped to the same point and shout not be seen as the base point. In fact by the universal property of quotient topology you know that these map are exactly the maps which have domain $S^1$. So you basically looking at self maps of $S^1$.

I would guess $(I,\{0,1\})$ is chosen in favor of $S^1$ to be in line with the covering space theory. It usually goes this way: if you have a covering and a *simply connected* space then a lift exists.

If you would require $\{0,1\}$ be mapped to $t_0$ then a lift does not have to exist. You could just map $I$ and $\Bbb R$ via the exponential $e^{2\pi t}$ to $S^1$. Then the lift has to be the inclusion up to $\Bbb Z$(a base point would give uniqueness). But the inclusion is injective so  $f'(1)\ne f'(0)$.